# How to collect data only when I click the start button using Tkinter and py Serial?

Tags: python, tkinter, sensors, pyserial

I have an USB GPS sensor and I'm trying to do a human/machine interface where the user click on the Start button and the data start collecting. To do that, I helped myself with this code http://robotic-controls.com/learn/python-guis/tkinter-serial.

I managed to get the data and have it on screen only when the user click on start button but I saw that when I click the button, lots of previous datas are displayed on the screen. My sensor provide me data each second, when I run my program, if I wait 5 seconds before clicking on the start button, I will have 5 rows displayed on the screen when I click on it.

Here is my code :

```py
import serial
import tkinter
from serial import *
from tkinter import *

gps = list()      
serialPort = "COM12"
baudRate = 4800
ser = Serial(serialPort , baudRate, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0)


root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Signal GPS")
etat = StringVar()
etat.set("Démarrer acquisition")

def StartStop():
    j=0
    if etat.get() == "Arreter acquisition" :
        etat.set("Reprendre acquisition")
        j=1

    if (etat.get() == "Démarrer acquisition" or etat.get() == "Reprendre acquisition") and j == 0 :
        etat.set("Arreter acquisition")        
        readSerial()

def quitter():
    root.destroy()


valeurs = Canvas(root)
valeurs.grid(column=0,row=0, padx=10)

texte_lati = Label(valeurs, text='Latitude')
texte_lati.grid(column=0, row=0)
lati = Text ( valeurs, width=20, height=20, takefocus=0)
lati.grid(column=0, row=1)

texte_longi = Label(valeurs, text='Longitude')
texte_longi.grid(column=1, row=0)
longi = Text ( valeurs, width=20, height=20, takefocus=0)
longi.grid(column=1, row=1)


start = Button(root, textvariable=etat, text=etat, command=StartStop)
start.grid(column=0,row=2)

quitte = Button(root, text='Quitter', command=quitter)
quitte.grid(column=1,row=2)


serBuffer = ""
def readSerial():

    while etat.get() == "Arreter acquisition" :                       
        c = ser.read().decode("latin1") 

        if len(c) == 0:
            break

        global serBuffer

        if c == '\r':
            c = '' 

        if c == '\n':
            if serBuffer[0:6] == '$GPGGA' :
                gps.append(serBuffer.split(','))
                serBuffer += "\n"

                if gps[-1][2] == '' :
                    lati.insert('0.0', 'Pas de signal GPS\n')

                else :
                    lati.insert('0.0', str(gps[-1][2]) + '\n')

                if gps[-1][4] == '' : 
                    longi.insert('0.0', 'Pas de signal GPS\n')
                else :
                    longi.insert('0.0', str(gps[-1][4]) + '\n')

            serBuffer = "" 

        else:
            serBuffer += c 

    root.after(100, readSerial) 


root.mainloop()
ser.close()
```

Can anyone explain me why I'm getting all the previous datas ? I expected that using `while etat.get() == "Arreter acquisition" :` will not store the data but it actually does...

Comment: using `import tkinter` and `from tkinter import *` is a bad idea - it loads the `tk` module into memory twice.